# Todo list Issues

Tags: javascript, html

Can some one help me? i'm trying to code a **simple todolist with JS** i'm 
begginer on this language, my tasks were adding ok, but when i created a button to complete the task it bugged the buttons, the add tasks is ok, deleting was ok too, but when i finish a task make it done, i can't make my action.

Receiving those errors When pressing my buttons **delete or done**.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (20:43:32:155 | error, javascript)
  at public_html/todo.js:65

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (20:43:32:252 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null (20:44:46:399 | error, javascript)
  at public_html/todo.js:65

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>TODO</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>TODOLIST</h1>

    <input id="task"><button id="add">Add</button>
    <hr>

    <h2>todo</h2>
    <ul id="todos"></ul>
    <h2>done</h2>
    <ul id="done"></ul>

    <script src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
function get_todos() {
var todos = new Array;
var todos_str = localStorage.getItem('todo');
if (todos_str !== null) {
    todos = JSON.parse(todos_str); 
}
return todos;
}

function get_dones(){
var dones = new Array;
var dones_str = localStorage.getItem('done');
if (dones_str !== null){
    dones = JSON.parse(dones_str);
}
return dones;
}


function add() {
var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

var todos = get_todos();
todos.push(task);
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

show();

return false;
}

function remove() {
var id = this.getAttribute('id');
var todos = get_todos();
todos.splice(id, 1);
localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));

show();

return false;
}

function show() {
var todos = get_todos();
var dones = get_dones();


var html;
for(var i=0; i<todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + todos[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">deletar</button> <button class="done" id="' + i  + '">Feito</button></li>';
};

document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

var html2;
for(var i=0; i<dones.length; i++) {
    html2 += '<li>' + dones[i] + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '">deletar</button> <button class="done" id="' + i  + '">Feito</button></li>';
};

document.getElementById('dones').innerHTML = html2;

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
};

    var buttons2 = document.getElementsByClassName('done');
for (var i=0; i < buttons2.length; i++) {
    buttons2[i].addEventListener('click', done);
};
}

function done(){
var id = this.getAttribute('id');
var done = get_dones();
localStorage.setItem('done', JSON.stringify(dones));

show();

return false;
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', add);
show();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's better if you tell us what your actual errors are - look in your browser console. Tell us what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: What's the error? Anything in the console?

Comment: "It bugged everything" is not a clear description of the issue or expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've tested more times and i found some errors, my post was edited with my errors now.
My goal is to create another Array for dones and a button to move a todo task for done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function

```
show()
```

is not closed correctly with a `}`

Within the `show()` function you have:

```
document.getElementById('dones').innerHTML = html;
```

however, your HTML has no element with an ID of "dones".

Next, in your function

```
function done(){
var id = this.getAttribute('id');
var done = get_dones();
localStorage.setItem('done', JSON.stringify(dones));
```

Your variable is named "done", but your are trying to stringify "dones".

Comment: Thanks for the help, my html didnt have any element of dones, because i want to move from todo to dones, and i don't know how i do that.